# windows api richtextbox adding extra linebreak in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi

I am making a hexadecimal editor in c++ windows api

I have a richtextbox and I am able to read the file just fine. The problem is when I write the file back out, the richtextbox adds some sort of line break character or something so the file will not output the same. I used messageboxes to look to see what the special character is and it appears to be some sort of line break because It will show my hexadecimal bytes in the messagebox and then on the part where the special character is inserted it will show my hexadecimal bytes in a slightly taller messagebox. I ran into this problem with an assembly program about 6 months ago and was able to fix it by removing all hexadecimal bytes "13" because their is no "\n" in assembly. so I tried to remove "\n" but it did not work, I also tried to remove "\t", "\f", "\r", "\n\r", "\r\n" and those don't remove it either. here is the code I used to try to remove the special characters (I found it on stack overflow and it seems like it works so I don't think it is the codes fault)

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n'), str.end());
```

I even tried to write a function that said if you find any "\n","\t", "\f", "\r", "\n\r", "\r\n" messagebox me but it never messageboxed me so it is some other special character.

so can someone please help me figure out what the special character is so I can remove it

thanks

**Update here is how to remove the linebreaks from a richtextbox in windows**

you have to remove '\r\n' and '\n' so here is the code to read the contents of a richtextbox into a string and remove the line breaks

```
textboxlength = GetWindowTextLength(hwndtextbox1);
GetWindowText(hwndtextbox1, buffert, textboxlength);
buffer4 = buffert;
                                          buffer4.erase(std::remove(buffer4.begin(), buffer4.end(), L'\r\n'), buffer4.end());
                                          buffer4.erase(std::remove(buffer4.begin(), buffer4.end(), L'\n'), buffer4.end());
```

textboxlength is a LONGLONG,buffert is a TCHAR and buffer4 is a wstring

Comment: `'\r\n'` is a multi-character literal the behavior of which isn't well defined, so I think that in reality you're just running two searches, one for `'\r'` and the second for `'\n'`. Nothing wrong with that but inefficient. I'll add some code to my answer that you can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses `CR+LF` as a standard line break marker - that is, two separate characters together - ASCII `13` followed by ASCII `10`. One or other by themselves won't generally be recognised as a line break.

Edit: Here's an example function to remove `CR+LF` from a `std::string`:

```
std::string RemoveLinebreak(std::string input)
{
    const std::string newline("\r\n");
    size_t pos = 0;
    while((pos = input.find(newline, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         input.erase(pos, newline.length());
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: I tried looking for "\r\n" and "\n\r" but it did not find it. is that how I look for CR+LF

Comment: I use GetwindowsText to read the text into a TCHAR, then convert the TCHAR to a wstring then try to remove the "\n\r" here is the code ----- GetWindowText(hwndtextbox1, buffert, 10000000);
            buffer4 = buffert;buffer4.erase(std::remove(buffer4.begin(), buffer4.end(), '\n\r'), buffer4.end());

Answer (score 0):

for wchar '\n' is L'\n' and '\n' is L'\n'

so basically you should use

`std::wstring str`

`str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), 'L\n'), str.end());`

or

`std::wstring str;`

`int pos;`

`pos=str.find_first_of(Text("\n\r"));`
`if(pos!=std::wstring::nops)str.erase(pos,pos+1);`